# Trying to make a basic calculator in C++, but I get a weird output

Tags: c++

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int result;
    char x;

    cout << "Enter one number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    
    cout << "Enter how you want to calculate: ";
    cin >> x;
    
    if(x == '+')
    {
        (num1 + num2) == result;
        cout << result;
      
    }
    else if(x == '-')
    {
        (num1 - num2) == result;
        cout << result;
        
    }
    else if(x == '*')
    {
        (num1*num2) == result;
        cout << result;
       
    }
    else if(x == '/')
    {
        (num1/num2) == result;
        cout << result;
        
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid parameter ";
      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
Enter one number: 1
Enter another number: 1
Enter how you want to calculate: +
32764
```

Comment: "Failure is always an option." -- Mythbusters.  What are the results from your debugging session?

Comment: `(num1 + num2) == result;` is wrong for several reasons, You are comparing num1 + num2 to the uninitialized variable result (not legal to examine a variable that has not been initialized) then throwing away the result of the comparison. However you didn't want to compare instead you wanted to assign  `result = num1 + num2;`

Answer (score 0):

The way you did your arithmetic operations is using the comparison "==" operator, not the assignment "=" operator, also they are in reverse order.

A basic assignment uses the form:

```
result = x * y;
```

Fix your code like so:

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int num1;
int num2;
int result;
char x;

cout << "Enter one number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter another number: ";
cin >> num2;

cout << "Enter how you want to calculate: ";
cin >> x;

if(x == '+')
{
    result = (num1 + num2);
    cout << result;
  
}
else if(x == '-')
{
    result = (num1 - num2);
    cout << result;
    
}
else if(x == '*')
{
     result = (num1*num2);
    cout << result;
   
}
else if(x == '/')
{
    result = (num1/num2);
    cout << result;
    
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid parameter ";
  
}
return 0;
}
```